# Open file and folder in other app

Tags: android

I got a activity that holds a path to a file (with unknown mime type).
I got 2 buttons. The one should open the folder in a file manager choosen by user.
The other should open the file in a application that fits to the filetype.
Clicking buttons work. openFolder let me choose a  filemanager: using androzip or root explorer takes me to sdcard but astro wants me to choose a file as if i upload a file to a oneclickhoster. OpenFile gives me no choise but opens a hex Editor which unfortunatli says the file is "null".

```
public void openFolder(View v)
{
    File f=new File(path);
    if(f.exists())
    {
        String folder=f.getAbsolutePath().replace("/"+f.getName(),"")+"/";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(folder);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "file/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));

    }

}

public void openFile(View v)
{
    File f=new File(path);
    if(f.exists())
    {
        //example for path: path=/storage/sdcard0/test.mp3
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT); 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:/"+path); 
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, getMIME()); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file"));
    }

}

private String getMIME()
{
    String type =null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    } 
    if(type.equals("") || type == null) 
        return "UNKNOWN";
    else
        return type;

}
```

EDIT: the problem for opening the file was Intent.ACTION_EDIT, it should be Intent.ACTION_VIEW.
But I still don't know how to open the folder.

Comment: "it doesn't work" does not give us anything to go on.

Comment: Ok, i updated the post... maybe that should help!